# How do I replace an image in a rotated and scaled UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, cgaffinetransform

I have a `UIView` with a `UIImageView` as a `subview`.  I modify the `UIView` with `CGAffineTransformRotate` and `CGAffineTransformScale`.  The `UIImageView` `subview` also transforms with it automatically.

I want to replace the `UIImage` in the `UIImageView` `subview` with a new `UIImage`.  When I do this, the `image` is the wrong size and `rotation`, because the original been scaled and rotated.

How do I replace the image `subview` and have it appear as the previous `image` did **(same size/rotation/location)**?

Answer (score 1):

Take another UIImageView2 and put your previous image in it first. Then after you scale and modify the original image to a new one and want to see your original one, you can show the UIImageView2 image.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I found the bug, see above.

Answer (score 1):

I found the bug, I was removing the original image and didn't know it.

```
imageView.image = nextImage;
```

Changing the image as above keeps the scale and rotation from the parent.  No trickery involved.